# spring-integration : how to delete a file?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm working on a simple spring-integration project that selects some files (using *file:inbound-channel-adapter*) and based on those files imports some data into DB.

At the end it would like to have those files deleted as I no longer need them and so far I haven't figured out how to do that without coding.

*file:outbound-channel-adapter* is no go as it moves files instead of deleting them.

I'm trying to solve it with

```
<int:outbound-channel-adapter expression="headers['file_originalFile'].delete()" ...
```

But I'm getting

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Void';

Do you have any ideas how to solve it without coding?

Comment: The error seems expected because spring expecting String expression and delete() returns void.  Have you looked at this http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html (14.3.4 File Outbound Channel Adapter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.delete()` returns a boolean and, by contract, an outbound channel adapter MUST return `void` (no output).

You can use a `<service-activator/>` with `output-channel="nullChannel"` to discard the result.

Or, you can use an expression evaluating advice on your ultimate consumer, as shown in the [retry-and-more sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Finally, I've modified the expression to `headers['file_originalFile'].delete()?null:null`. I have to say though, that I'm pretty surprised that the delete functionality doesn't work out of the box in spring-integration. It seems to me that my scenario is quite typical ans still I had to find the way to "hack" it without coding. For me it should be implemented in _outbound-channel-adapter_